# Python modulus result is incorrect

Tags: python

I am totally stumped. I was computing the cipher of the number 54 in RSA with the following values:

p=5; q=29; n=145
d=9; e=137

So the number 54 encrypted would be:

54^137 mod 145

or equivalently in python:

```
import math
math.pow(54,137)%145
```

My calculator gives me 24, my python statement gives me 54.0. Python is clearly wrong but I have no idea why or how. Try it on your installations of Python. My version is 2.5.1 but I also tried on 2.6.5 with the same incorrect result.

Answer (score 14):

```
>>> pow(54,137,145)
24
```

`math.pow` is floating point.  You don't want that.  Floating-point values have less than 17 digits of useful precision.  The 54**137 has 237 digits.

Comment: Thanks! Interesting information, I love learning little details like this.

Comment: @Franz: "little details"?  Like floating point only represents only a few decimal digits of precision?  I think that this is more than little.  There are a fair number of SO questions that reflect other folks not knowing this piece of information.  Or perhaps you were referring to something else?

Answer (score 9):

That's because using the `math` module is basically just a Python wrapper for the C math library which doesn't have arbitrary precision numbers. That means `math.pow(54,137)` is calculating 54^137 as a 64-bit floating point number, which means it will not be precise enough to hold all the digits of such a large number.  Try this instead to use Python's normal built-in arbitrary precision integers:

```
>>> (54 ** 137) % 145
24L
```

Comment: Using 3-argument `pow(x, y, z)` instead of `x ** y % z` for modulus arithmetic is generally a very good idea - it avoids the need to create the potentially huge intermediate value `x ** y`.